# Data Manipulation and Structuring in R

Tags: r, matrix, data-structures, data-manipulation

I have an 'Exp' data set which looks like this:

```
  Locals   Res   Ind
1    112 7.865 4.248
2    113 4.248 5.666
3    114 5.666 2.444
4    115 2.444 7.865
5    116 7.865 4.248
6    117 4.248 6.983
7    118 5.666 3.867
8    119 2.444 2.987
```

And I have another data set called 'Com' as below:

```
113 112 113
112 114 119
116 118 119
118 118 119
117 117 119
117 117 119
```

I want to create two matrices called 'Res' and 'Ind' based on the value in the Com data, match it to the first row, Local, of the Exp data and get the corresponding value from the 'Res' or 'Ind' column depending on the matrix it is created for. 
For eg - The first value in the Com data set is 113 so in the Res matrix the first value will be 4.248 - because the corresponding value in Exp's first column of 113 is 4.248.
Such that the Res matrix will look something like this

```
4.248   7.865   4.248
7.865   5.666   2.444
7.865   5.666   2.444
5.666   5.666   2.444
4.248   4.248   2.444
4.248   4.248   2.444
```

Can anybody please suggest a easy way to do this on R. If there are many matrices required to be created and many values in Exp's first row then what is the quickest way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
structure(dat1$Res[match(unlist(dat2),dat1[,1])],.Dim=dim(dat2))

[1,] 4.248 7.865 4.248
[2,] 7.865 5.666 2.444
[3,] 7.865 5.666 2.444
[4,] 5.666 5.666 2.444
[5,] 4.248 4.248 2.444
[6,] 4.248 4.248 2.444

structure(dat1$Ind[match(unlist(dat2),dat1[,1])],.Dim=dim(dat2))

     [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
[1,] 5.666 4.248 5.666
[2,] 4.248 2.444 2.987
[3,] 4.248 3.867 2.987
[4,] 3.867 3.867 2.987
[5,] 6.983 6.983 2.987
[6,] 6.983 6.983 2.987
```

You can do this in one line:

```
lapply(Exp[-1],function(x) structure(x[match(as.matrix  (  Com),Exp[,1])],.Dim=dim(Com)))

$Res
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
[1,] 4.248 7.865 4.248
[2,] 7.865 5.666 2.444
[3,] 7.865 5.666 2.444
[4,] 5.666 5.666 2.444
[5,] 4.248 4.248 2.444
[6,] 4.248 4.248 2.444

$Ind
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
[1,] 5.666 4.248 5.666
[2,] 4.248 2.444 2.987
[3,] 4.248 3.867 2.987
[4,] 3.867 3.867 2.987
[5,] 6.983 6.983 2.987
[6,] 6.983 6.983 2.987
```